# Induction mathematics

Tags: induction

Assume $a_1 = 4$ and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3+2a_n}$ for all integers $n ≥ 1$. Show with induction that $\forall n ≥ 1, \space a_n  > a_{n+1} > 3$. 
Help me solve this please

Comment: I have not solved such problem before, I have solved "normal" induction problems where you replace n with = p and then to show that p is real for all p you replace p with p+1 and solve it. But never seen this kind of question, that's why.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly holds for $n=1$ since $a_1 = 4$ and $a_2 = \sqrt{11}$.

Assuming it holds for some $k$, that is, $\space a_k  > a_{k+1} > 3$, then it holds for $a_{k+1}$ since

$a_{k+2} = \sqrt{3+2a_{k+1}} < a_{k+1} = \sqrt{3+2a_{k}} $ since $a_{k} > a_{k+1}$

and $a_{k+2} = \sqrt{3+2a_{k+1}} > \sqrt{9} = 3$ since $a_{k+1}>3$.

Note that we use the fact that the square-root function is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $a_n - a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3+2a_{n-1}}-\sqrt{3+2a_n} = \dfrac{2(a_{n-1}-a_n)}{\sqrt{3+2a_{n-1}}+\sqrt{3+2a_n}}$, and $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{3+2a_n} > \sqrt{3+2(3)} = 3$

Comment: I have learned I am suppose to use different stages of induction method. Can you help me using it?

Comment: the hint ..yells loudly the steps for ya...already...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two parts. First part: prove that $a_n>3$, for every $n$; second part: prove that $a_n>a_{n+1}$, for every $n$.

### First part

The induction base is obvious, as $a_1=4>3$. Suppose $a_n>3$. Then $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3+2a_n}>\sqrt{3+6}=\sqrt{9}=3$.

### Second part

Since $a_n>3>0$, the inequality $a_n>a_{n+1}$ is equivalent to
$$
a_n^2>3+2a_n
$$
that is,
$$
a_n^2-2a_n-3>0
$$
or
$$
(a_n-3)(a_n+1)>0
$$
which is true, because $a_n>3$.